# sql patern match to find a space or character

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working in SQL Server 2008 R2. I am creating a query to look for a specific set of characters, such as 'ACS' but I don't want to return results that contain 'Non ACS' or 'Non-ACS' (Why the person(s) who entered the data couldn't be consistent is beyond me). I am wanting to use a regex to keep the query short. What I have tried is:

```
WHERE ((tblTasks.strTask LIKE '%ACS%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS) AND (tblTasks.strTask NOT LIKE '%NON[-, ]ACS%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS))
```

which doesn't work.

I am trying to avoid the following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE ((tblTasks.strTask LIKE '%ACS%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS) AND ((tblTasks.strTask NOT LIKE '%NON-ACS%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS) AND (tblTasks.strTask NOT LIKE '%NON ACS%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS)))
```

How does one find either the space or the dash between the two words/character sets?

And if I could do something like this that would be cool:

```
WHERE (tblTasks.strTask LIKE '%^[NON]^[-, ]ACS%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS)
```

Comment: if you just trying to find space or dash you can just simply look for `mycolumn like '% %' or mycolumn like '%-%'` I don't understand why you need regular expression.

Comment: Does it have a REGEX_LIKE ?

Comment: @VladimirOselsky I need the regular expression because I only want rows with 'ACS' in them but not 'NON ACS' or 'NON-ACS'. Using '% %' or '%-%' will return unrelated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from <table> 
WHERE field LIKE '%ASC%' and field not like '%NON[ ,-]ASC%'


create table #lookfor (theFld VARCHAR(200))
insert into #lookfor 
   values ('ASC'),('NON-ASC'),('NON ASC'),('NON,ASC')

select * from #lookfor   

select * from #lookfor where thefld like '%ASC%'
         and theFld not like '%NON[ ,-]ASC%'

drop table #lookfor
```

Comment: I could have swore I tried this yesterday and it didn't work, but it does work! Now if only I can distill this down one clause. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if sql server can do regex's or what engine if it does, but
a modern engine would be able to do this regex.

Could be done using just a lookbehind like this `ACS(?<!(?i:Non)[- ]ACS)`  or
with a lookahead, depending on what else is needed in the qualification.

```
 #  (?=ACS(?<!Non[- ]ACS))     

 (?=                       # Lookahead to find the 'ACS'
      ACS
      (?<! Non [- ] ACS )       # Inner lookbehind, not 'Non ACS' nor 'Non-ACS'
 )
 # Here, we matched 'ACS'
```

If case might be a factor i.e. 'NON', just scope it as case insensitive, 'ACS' is still forced caps.

`(?=ACS(?<!(?i:Non)[- ]ACS))`

Comment: Regexes can only be used in SQL Server if a CLR function is defined and loaded to do so, in which case it uses the .NET variety of regular expressions.  See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx).